# Creating a new dataframe column which returns the position of another column's element as it appears in a given list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list:

```
A_List <- (A, B, C, D, E)
```

I have a df:

```
A <- c(A, C, E, D, B) 
B <- (Z, Y, X, W, V)
```

I would like to create a "New" column whose values are derived by viewing each element in column "A" and returning the index of the element as it appears in list A.

| A | B | **New** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Z | **1** |
| C | Y | **3** |
| E | X | **5** |
| D | W | **4** |
| B | V | **2** |

I have tried using ifelse() with grep but it only takes the first element:

`df$New <- ifelse(df$A %in% A_List, grep(df$A, A_List), 0)`

Comment: Just realised my example wasn’t consistent with the code I’d tried so edited for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below with `match`

```
transform(df, New = match(A,A_List))
```

Answer (score 3):

`baseR` way

```
df$New <- match(df$A, A_list)
```

`dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)
A <- c("A", "C", "E", "D", "B")
B <- c("Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V")
df <- data.frame(A, B)
A_list = LETTERS[1:5]

df %>% mutate(New = match(A, A_list))
  A B New
1 A Z   1
2 C Y   3
3 E X   5
4 D W   4
5 B V   2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, New := match(A, A_list)]
```